# Error: conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'person' requested

Tags: c++, class, memory, data-structures

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class person{
public:
  string name;
  int age;
};
person* createPerson() {
    person* p = malloc(sizeof(class person));
    p.name = "Ken";
    p.age = 10;
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    
    return 0;
}

//Here is the source code. in createPerson function, when I allocate memory for a class it reports an error
```

The error: conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'person' requested. I am so confused. How can I fix it?

Comment: `person p = malloc(sizeof(class person));` -> `person p;`

Comment: Don't use `malloc()` in c++ code. That's wrong anyways

Comment: just remove the `= malloc...` stuff. Apart from being wrong, it's not needed.

Answer (score 3):

C++ allocates memory for you when you declare a variable

```
person createPerson() {
    person p; // allocates memory for p
    p.name = "Ken";
    p.age = 10;
    return p;
}
```

In C++ you should never use `malloc`, the C++ version is `new`. But `new` is used for dynamic memory allocation, which is a whole different ball game and completely unnecessary in the code you have shown us.

Comment: Also, in C++, you should never use `new`. Just use `make_unique` and `vector`.